# Regularity of measure in Lemma 7.2.6 of Bogachev

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, borel-measures

In the book "Measure Theory" of Bogachev, vol. 2, Lemma 7.2.6 states the following.

> Let $\mu$ be a $\tau$-additive, *regular* Borel measure on a topological space $X$, and let $\{f_\alpha\}$ be an increasing net of lower-semicontinuous non-negative functions such that $f:= \lim_\alpha f_\alpha$ is bounded. Then 
>   $$
> \lim_\alpha \int_X f_\alpha \, d\mu \quad = \quad \int_X f \, d\mu .
> $$

In the proof it is quite clear where the $\tau$-additivity comes into play. However, I cannot see why we need $\mu$ to be *regular*. Bogachev defines this property in the following way (paraphrasing its Definition 7.1.5):

> A measure $\mu$ on a topological space $X$ is called *regular* if for every measurable set $A\subseteq X$ and for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a closed set $C_\varepsilon \subseteq A$ such that $\mu(A) - \mu(C_\varepsilon) < \varepsilon$.

Is regularity of $\mu$ in Lemma 7.2.6 then really necessary?

Comment: Might it be related to the limit over $\alpha$?

Comment: maybe it would be possible that a lower-semicontinuous function would be not measurable if $\mu$ is not regular

Comment: @FedePoncio I don't think so, since that's what $\tau$-additivity takes care of.

Comment: @Masacroso I don't think so, measurability of a function does not depend on the measure (but only on the $\sigma$-algebra, which here is fixed - it is the Borel one).

Comment: @Dap I think that the measure in your example is not $\tau$-additive either. Right?

Comment: @geodude: right, I had missed the $\tau$-additive condition. For what its worth, I read the proof and agree it doesn't need regularity anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an authoritative reference: "Measure Theory" by D. H. Fremlin, vol. 4. 
Point a) of Corollary 414B therein says the following (the notes in the brackets are mine):

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mu$ an effectively locally finite (for example, finite) $\tau$-additive topological (for example, Borel) measure on $X$. Suppose that $A$ is a non-empty upwards-directed family of lower-semicontinuous functions from $X$ to $[0.\infty]$. Set 
>   $$
> g(x) := \sup_{f\in A} f(x)
> $$
>   for all $x\in X$. Then 
>   $$
> \int g \, d\mu = \sup_{f\in A} \int f\,d\mu .
> $$

Modulo the difference in the notation, this implies the assert in the question.